# How to write strings which is already have new line character using streamwriter in C#?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a string which has \n character in some parts. I want to write that string into text file. I try Write and WriteLine method of streamwriter and in both it writes in a single line. So, is there any simple way to write this string using its new line character or should a split it into array by \n character.

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog sfd = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "g-code|*.gcode;";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(sfd.FileName);
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sfd.OpenFile());
            writer.Write(GcodeTxt);
            writer.Dispose();
            writer.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("File is saved.", "Saved", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
```

Sample GcodeTxt:"G21;metric is good!\n G90  ;absolute positioning\n T0 ;select new extruder\n G28 ;go home\n G92 E0 ;set extruder home\n M104 S73.0 ;set temperature\n"

And the result is;

[image]

Comment: Is GcodeTxt a large amount of data or a small amount of data?

Comment: Note that Windows Notepad only reads `\r\n` line endings, not just `\n`. Try opening your file in something like Notepad++ and see if it looks like it should.

Comment: I open it in notepad++ and it is what I expected. So, to do that in windows notepad should I include \r every place near \n?

Comment: Yes. The easiest would be to use `Environment.NewLine` which will return `\r\n` on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your `GcodeTxt` probably has the \n formatted as a regular string and not a special character. Even if you add \r\n to your text, it will just get formatted as regular string chars.</strike>

Use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n` for cross env newlines:
`(@"G21;metric is good!" + Environment.NewLine + @" G90 ;...`

Answer (score 2):

Fix the line separator in your strings to match what the platform expects. Windows expects `\r\n`. Use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`. Your string has been generated in the wrong way. Fix the way it is being built.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Notepad reads only CrLf *(Carriage return + Line feed)* line endings, which is `\r\n`. If you put only a line feed character (`\n`) then Notepad will render it as if it were written in a single line.

Try opening your file in something like Notepad++ and it should look as you want it to.

To write a Carriage return + Line feed, use `Environment.NewLine` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are accurate.  However, you should also consider using `StreamWriter.WriteLine` instead of `StreamWriter.Write` when you want to insert a newline.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It depends if he is getting the different lines in chunks or just as a long string